# Paper size stuck in Windows 10

Tags: printer

Regardless of which paper size I pick for any printer, be it my default printer, or the Microsoft PDF printer, or an office copier, my document will end up using that weird size (picture attached, it's a rather narrow, look like a 1:2 ratio).

As a result anything that I currently print is zoomed in and truncated as if I was trying to print a regular size letter document on that odd size paper.

Has anyone encountered this before ?

I should mention, I am using Windows 10, and tried printing from Firefox, Word, Excel, and Notepad, all with the same results. 
Currently listed printers:

- Fax
- Konica C287 copier - Default
- Konica C367 copier
- Lexmark forms printer 2580
- Microsoft Print to PDF
- Microsoft XPS document writer
- OneNote
- Send to OneNote 2010
- Send to OneNote 2016

[Example of letter document printed to PDF with letter paper size selected in the printer options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BAZPG.png)

[Paper size that I can't change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pyDRX.png)

Comment: Are you sure the problem isn't just the invoice itself?  I assume you have selected "fit to page" option?  Is the invoice Landscape or Portrait?

Comment: Is this a Word document? In that case, go to Page Setup and set the paper size. Word saves paper size with the document and ignores printer settings.

Comment: That's the odd part, I've tried to print from multiple sources, Adobe Reader, Notepad, Word, Excel and get the same result every time.
Another thing is the paper size preview never changes either (see image "Paper Size that I can't change". Doesn't matter which paper I select in the settings.

Comment: Landscape or portrait produce a truncated result. I've checked that the fit to page option, but it makes no difference :/

Comment: The problem stopped happening once pending Windows updates got applied. Hard to pinpoint the source now. So how can I close a question with no real answer ? (since I don't feel that "apply windows update to fix unrelated issue" constitute much of an answer)

Comment: @Anth0, what a surprise...

Comment: Yes, we are seing a very similar problem. Windows 10, using an old MS Word from MS Office 2010 and printing goes zombie, in our case showing all the settings as "A4" but printing as if "legal". When I open the documents with other tools, they show that internally the setting is as "legal". Sadly I cannot directly edit .doc files in a text editor, as it is binary and I do not know where to hack.

Comment: @Anth0 Yes, you should create your own answer, even if so simple. When I looked at your question last week, I missed the fact that you consider this problem as "stopped happening" because I do not normally read all those comments. Also in the overview pages, the number of answers get listed, but not the number of "helpful comments" and your question so far has no answsers.

Comment: In our own case, we managed to get our zombie Word document converted to a more recent version of MS Office and the problem went away. This is probably material for a different question.

Comment: @MartinZaske, thanks for letting me know, added the previous comment as accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem stopped happening once pending Windows updates got applied.
Wish I had knew why, but that's what fixed the issue.